# Is primitivity invariant under matrix conjugation.

Tags: matrices

Given a primitive matrix $A$. Is it true that it is only similar to other primitive matrices?

Comment: all entries positive doesn't mean eigenvalues are positive. See matrix with all entries as $1$.

Comment: O ok. I see, sorry. Let me rephrase my question though.

Comment: still, we can try to make skew symmetric matrix $[0,1;1,0]$ to make the eigenvalues as $1,-1$.

Comment: what does it mean for a matrix to be primitive?

Comment: @IttayWeiss See [Perron-Frobenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A primitive matrix may be similar to a non-primitive matrix. For instance, $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: As usual,you gave the best possible example, +1.